# How can I customize special icons

Tags: install4j

I'm evaluating Install4j to see if that's a possible substitute for InstallAnywhere.
Customizing icons for Installer/Unistaller [Executable icons] is quite clear for me. The possibility to customize the image in the title bar is also clear.
I was asking me if there's also a custom option for the following icons during the Installation:

[image]

[image]

The solution (if there's one) muss be for a specific project. I don't want to affect other projects with this change.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshots shows the installer icon which can be customized by setting the "Executable icon" property of the installer on the Installer->Screens & Actions step.

Comment: absolutely correct... my fault... with cross-platform Image is possible to achive this goal... thanks